# How can I store my Google Drive Service to avoid recreat it in each call?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, delegation

I'm using the code above, from https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation, to get access to a specific Google Drive account:

```
function buildService($userEmail) {
    global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH;
    $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
    $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
        $key);
    $auth->sub = $userEmail;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setUseObjects(true);
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
    return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
```

It Works fine, but is very slow the creation of the object. I want to store the service in the session to avoid recreating it in each request to the server. Serialize is not possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your service in the same script execution, you can make a Singleton to store all methods you need.

In this case, your class is instanciated once, and when you call once more, the previous instance is returned instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks, Corum, but I need to reuse it in another request to the server, in the same session.

Comment: In this case, you can try to use APC cache to improve performances : [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)